# Users cannot see Change Status button on Case View page

Tags: permissions, button

I've noticed that some of our users cannot see the Close or Change Status buttons which normally appear in the cases List Views. They have permissions to read, create and edit cases.

I have checked in the search layouts that all the buttons are available.
I found this question posed on here over a year ago and it said the users didn't have the "Manage Cases" permission but I don't see any permission named "Manage Cases".

Grateful for any help on how to get these buttons to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This permission is under the App Permissions section.

[image]

Comment: There it is! Thanks so much...I didn't know it was specific to the Call Center, I was checking the System Settings.

Comment: Is easy to miss them :). You can accept this answer to help others users having the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, we can have 'Change Status' button on the cases(standard object) list view in lightning, firstly we need to understand that 'Change Status' is a quick action and it was default quick action in Classic but once we switch to lightning, it doesn't seems to be default actions in lightning. So, we need to create 'Change Status' action in lightning and then we have to add it in the 'selected quick actions' from list view button layout of case object.
Steps:

1. Create a quick actions from Case object named Change Status and give all the relevant details.
2. Go to case list view from Case Search layouts.
3. Add the newly created action in the list of Selected quick action.
   [image]

and here it is on lightning page.
[image]